# I have the same code in two different applications but in one I have this OperationContextScope being disposed out of order

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-6.0

After reading documentation and forums, I saw that the problem is generated because I'm using an await inside an `OperationContextScope`. I'm using ASP.NET Core 6 MVC and C#.

The problem is that the code is replicated in two different applications, literally they have the same code, but in one I have the `OperationContextScope` error and in the other one not.

```
using (new OperationContextScope(client.InnerChannel))
{                       
    SoapAuthenticationHeader.Create(client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName, 
    client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password);

    zWsGetList = CreateZWSGetListObject(param);

    var GetListResponse1 = await client.GetListAsync(zWGetList);

    // Rest of the code
}
```

I used breakpoints but it breaks after when it exits the breakpoint.

Sorry if I'm wrong in something that may be a rookie, but it seems very strange to me that in one application it works perfectly and in the other it doesn't, and both of them are EXACTLY the same. Maybe is a nuget package?

Answer (score 0):

I installed this NuGet and it finally worked:

```
System.ComponentModel.Annotations
System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager
System.ServiceModel.Duplex
System.ServiceModel.Federation
System.ServiceModel.Http
System.ServiceModel.NetTcp
System.ServiceModel.Security
```

Some of them came by default, other I had to install manually. Hope You find this usefull.